# Magento problems - manual module installation

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a problem after manual module installation. I checked errors reports in var/report folder and i have this:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:74:"Mage registry key "_singleton/mageplace_hideprice/observer" already exists";i:1;s:4382:"#0 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/app/Mage.php(222): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/app/Mage.php(476): Mage::register('_singleton/mage...', false)
#2 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(21023): Mage::getSingleton('mageplace_hidep...')
#3 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#4 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(2542): Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#5 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(2237): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(2177): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('optional_zip_co...', true)
#7 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/html/head.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml()
#8 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(3223): include('/var/zpanel/hos...')
#9 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(3254): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/ultimo...')
#10 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(3268): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#11 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(2518): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(2237): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(2181): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('head', true)
#14 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(35): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('head')
#15 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(3223): include('/var/zpanel/hos...')
#16 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(3254): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/ultimo...')
#17 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(3268): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(2518): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(27393): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(13553): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#21 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(10913): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#22 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(10828): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#23 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#24 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(13582): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#25 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(17927): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#26 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(17484): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#27 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/includes/src/__default.php(20061): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#28 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#29 /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/sklep_colourlock_pl/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#30 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Mage registry key “_singleton/core/resource” already exists is a common problem during updates & installations.

This particular problem comes from the Magento Extension 'hide price' from Amesty. The problem occurs when you enable the compilation without compiling first. To fix it, compile and run again:

First get back in the backend by:
- clear the cache of the website through ftp: delete the contents of the var/cache folder. 
- delete the new module xml-files in app\etc\modules\ to get back on the admin panel.

now, login in backend & disable complilation
- place back the xml-files of the module

- compile
- enable compilation.

That should do the trick. 
You can place the xml file back